# Can't find GPT4ALL model

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain, gpt4all

I am writing a program in Python, I want to connect GPT4ALL so that the program works like a GPT chat, only locally in my programming environment. To do this, I already installed the GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin model (here is the download link: https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/GPT4All-13B-snoozy-GGML/resolve/main/GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin), I have the model locally, location: C:\Models\GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin. As far as I understand, the problem is in the installation of GPT4ALL. But I ran the `pip install gpt4all` command in the terminal and it downloads everything and everything works (it does not give an error).The program sees the model, but gives the following error when running the code: `Found model file at  C:\\Models\\GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin Unable to load the model: 1 validation error for GPT4All __root__   Unable to instantiate model (type=value_error) Invalid model file  Process finished with exit code 0` I am writing code in PyCharm (If it is important), the langchain library is installed and working (its latest version). The program sees and finds the model, but gives this error. I downloaded the model from this site: https://gpt4all.io/index.html. Used the official langchain documentation to connect. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I tried to download other models from the same site - gave the same error. Also changed the format of the model - did not work.

Comment: You are just reasking the same question that was closed, do not do that.